# i get undefined when i run node js code while trying to read a file using fs

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, filesystems, backend

i started learning node js and decided to learn to read files using fs:filesystem

```
//to read files

var fs=require('fs')

fs.readFile('calc.js','UTF-8',function(err,data){
    console.log(data)
})
```

so  in the terminal i run my code using node app.js and it return undefined

C:\Users\faouz\nodeex> node "c:\Users\faouz\nodeex\tempCodeRunnerFile.js"
undefined

Comment: `function(err,data)`,  and what did `err` show?

Comment: Probably the file doesn't exist in the same folder.

Comment: thank you so muuch hahah , i asked my self the same thing , i made a misttake in the name of the file

Comment: that was the error

Comment: [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\faouz\nodeex\calc.js'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\faouz\\nodeex\\calc.js'
}

Answer (score 0):

I think I made a mistake in the name of the file, now it's working perfectly

> [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\faouz\nodeex\calc.js'] {
> errno: -4058,
> code: 'ENOENT',
> syscall: 'open',
> path: 'C:\Users\faouz\nodeex\calc.js'
> }